# How to show serial number at listing page with pagination in cakephp 3.x

Tags: pagination, cakephp-3.0

I want to show serial number on each row using pagination in cakephp 3.x.
Please suggest how can we implement?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.. can I ask what have you tried so far? can you add some more details about what you have searched and what do you plan to accomplish?

Comment: I want to display serial number in each row on view page. e.g.  if 10 record show at page 1 then 1 to 10 serial number will be show in each row.

Comment: What do you mean by serial number?  The primary ID of the row or some  'counter' that adds +1 to every iteration? (A ordered list in HTML)

Comment: I want counter that adds +1 every iteration. i am using cakephp 3.x pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is answer :

$sr_no=($this->request->params['paging']['AffiliatePrograms']['page']-1) * $this->request->params['paging']['AffiliatePrograms']['perPage'];
foreach ($affiliate_programs as $affiliate_program): 
                $sr_no++;

endforeach;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic

```
$sl_no = (($current_page_number - 1) * $limit) + 1 ;
```

then inside `foreach echo $sl_no++;`

Answer (score 0):

Here the logic 
Before loop

```
$num = $this->Paginator->counter('{:start}');
```

inside loop

```
$num = $num + 1;
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
//outside the loop

$num = $this->Paginator->counter('{{start}}')-1;

//inside the loop   
$num ++
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

//outside the loop

$num = $this->Paginator->counter('{{start}}');

//inside the loop
$num ++

e.g. 1,2,3, .... n